# How can you change the starting position of the major axis labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis-labels

How can I change the starting position of a ggplot2 axis label?

Here is my code:

```
# data - dataframe
# y - string used to get certain column of data frame
graph_data <- function(data, y, title = "Stand in") {
  y <- sym(y)
  connected_scatter <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!y)) +
    theme_linedraw() + geom_point() + geom_line() +
    ggtitle(title) + 
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m.%Y", date_breaks = "3 months", date_minor_breaks = "1 month")
  return(connected_scatter)
}
```

Here is a segment of what what I currently have outputs:

[image: Plot segment]

What I would like is to offset the date labels by one month in the positive direction, e.g. 11.2020 -> 12.2020, 02.2021 -> 03.2021, etc. I want to actually move them on the graph to the next month as well, not just change the label text. I tried to use the "limits" option on the [ggplot2 scale_x_date() documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why note just add a month to the `dates` column?

Comment: If you have the lubridate package active, you could simply specify `x = dates + period(1, 'month')`

Answer (score 0):

Edit due to previous answer not working.

This is what I came up with:

```
get_every_third <- function(data) {
  return(data[seq(3, length(data), 3)])
}

graph_data <- function(data, y, title = "Stand in") {
  y <- sym(y)
  connected_scatter <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!y)) +
    theme_linedraw() + geom_point() + geom_line() +
    ggtitle(title) + 
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m.%Y", breaks = get_every_third(data$dates), date_minor_breaks = "1 month")
  return(connected_scatter)
}
```

Using other methods either did not work or was much more challenging.